# React Google BarChart max column limit?

Tags: reactjs, charts

I am using React Google Chart to display data in a bar chart and table.

Both the table and bar chart get the same data, but the table shows all 20 entries, while the bar chart only shows the first 10.

Is there a limit on the number of bar charts arrays it can display? If so, is it possible to show all 20 arrays?

Notes:

The chart has to display max and min diameter in km for 20 objects, but the first object is over 1.5 km, and the last 10 objects get down to around 0.03km.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import BarChart from '../components/Chart';

const dataColumnTitles = ["name", "min estimated diameter", "max estimated diameter"];

class MainPage extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  };

componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataHandler();
};


getDataHandler = () => {
    axios.get("https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse? 
 api_key=DEMO_KEY")
    .then(response => {
        const restructuredData = response.data.near_earth_objects.map(
            ({name, estimated_diameter}) => {
                return [
                    name,
                    estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_min,
                    estimated_diameter.kilometers.estimated_diameter_max,
                ];
            }
        );
        this.setState({data: [dataColumnTitles, ...restructuredData]})

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};


render(){
  const { data } = this.state;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <BarChart chartData={data}/>
    </React.Fragment>
)}};

export default MainPage;
```

Comment: will you please share the code for the bar chart? there should not be a limit...

Comment: Without the code for Chart we cannot help you, since there is no limit for bar chart, or there is no limit in docs

Comment: It can't be the code because if i console.log the state where the array is i see 20 results and all that happens after is they are passed straight to the chart with props. And that must work because it shows 10 results instead of nothing or a error.

Comment: @Ivar515 it must be your code because I just passed array with 40 elements to BarChart on their official site and it works as it should. Go there and try for your self, code part in docs is editable https://react-google-charts.com/bar-chart

Comment: Ok added the code for when i just had get api and the chart and even then it only displays 10.